# Convert a $_GET value in PDO

Tags: sql, pdo

I wrote a basic function to join 3 tables regarding a similar `id`.

```
    {
        $id = $_GET["id"];
        $product_edit_query = $this->DB->query('
            SELECT * FROM products
            LEFT JOIN products_ingredients
            ON products_ingredients.product_id = products.product_id
            LEFT JOIN products_languages
            ON products_languages.product_id = products.product_id
            WHERE products.product_id = 73
        ');
        $product_edit = $product_edit_query->fetch();
        $this->smarty->assign('product_edit', $product_edit);
    }
```

In the last line I have of my request, i have `WHERE products.product_id = 73`. 73 is hardcoded, and should be the value of `$_GET["id"]`, but all I tried didn't work to convert it in PDO, any help ?

Comment: Do you know how to concatenate in PHP? Also, you absolutely should not do it this way. You are begging for SQL injection. Use binding instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution given by a friend:

```
    {
        $stmt = $this->DB->prepare('
            SELECT * FROM products
            LEFT JOIN products_ingredients
            ON products_ingredients.product_id = products.product_id
            LEFT JOIN products_languages
            ON products_languages.product_id = products.product_id
            WHERE products.product_id = :id
        ');
        $stmt->execute([':id' => $_GET["id"]]);
        $get_product_base = $stmt->fetch();
        $this->smarty->assign('get_product_base', $get_product_base);
    }
```